# Set up G933 Logitech headset to switch profiles manually

Tags: wireless-headset, logitech-headset

I am trying to use my G933 Logitech headset  in a work environment. It seems to be more game oriented so I am having some issues getting it working how I want.

The current profiles in the device are attached to specific applications (games) and seem to be designed to switch automatically. I instead would like to easelly flip between the two my goal is this"

Normal mode: Green lights, equaliser set to music friendly.

Meeting mode: colors are red, equaliser set to communications

I see that the software supports profiles, but my problem is i am not sure how to switch between them, as in a meeting i don't necessarily focus, my windows on the meetings app, and instead usually work int he same applications as I do when not in a meeting

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this same issue until today that I revisited the topic.  This is how I solved it:

First, I created a script using AutoHotKey that opens a window that only exists (does nothing but float and have an Exit button) and compiled the script into an exe file.

Then, I created 2 profiles with the settings I want.  The Default profile with the regular settings for all I usually do (like your Normal mode).  A profile for being On a Call (like your meeting mode).  I set this On a Call profile to be active when I execute the script I created before and checked the "Lock profile while game is running" option.

Essentially, you could use any other program you run while you're in a meeting, but I don't really have a program that running for that and using Lync.exe doesn't really work as each time I focused on it the profiles would change, so I ended up creating a tiny program that would serve this purpose.

This is the script I created, whose only option is to click the exit button:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
WinX := (A_ScreenWidth - 166 )*4 / 5
WinY := (A_ScreenHeight - 80) / 5
Gui, Show, x%WinX% y%WinY% W100 H50, --- On a Call ---
WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On, --- On a Call ---
Gui, Add, Button, W80 H40, Exit
Gui, -SysMenu
Return

ButtonExit:
ExitApp
```

Answer (score 1):

The Logitech software comes with pre-configured options to map G buttons to turn on/off the Advanced Equalizer, as well as the surround sound, leaving a pretty flat sound profile that's very close to the Communications profile in the Advanced Equalizer field.

If you want to get fancy, it also comes pre-configured with options to map increasing mic volume to a button, decreasing it to another, as well pre-configured options to map increase/decrease side tone.